# Batch file for deleting old folders from network not working

Tags: batch-file, backup

I have created a batch file which should keep the 4 newest folders on a network. This is because it is a back up of one of the computers.
I tested it first on my own system and it worked correctly. After testing I copied the batch to the other system and let it run by the Task Scheduler of Windows. It does make back ups, but it will not remove the oldest folders. I gave that task all needed permissions. I will paste the code here, because I think there could be a fault in the code.

```
@echo off
WMIC.EXE Alias /? >NUL 2>&1 || GOTO s_error

FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
   IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
      Set _yyyy=%%L
      Set _mm=00%%J
      Set _dd=00%%G
)
:s_done

  Set _mm=%_mm:~-2%
  Set _dd=%_dd:~-2%

Set _isodate=%_yyyy%-%_mm%-%_dd%
Echo %_isodate%
@echo off

for /F "skip=4 delims=" %%I in ('dir "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup1\backup1_*" /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup1\%%I"
for /F "skip=4 delims=" %%I in ('dir "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup2\backup2_*" /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup2\%%I"
for /F "skip=4 delims=" %%I in ('dir "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup3\backup3_*" /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup3\%%I"
for /F "skip=4 delims=" %%I in ('dir "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup4\backup4_*" /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup4\%%I"

@echo off

cd C:\
ROBOCOPY "C:\backup1" "\\server\Folder1\folder1\backup1\backup1"_%_isodate% /COPYALL /E /W:5 /R:5
ROBOCOPY "C:\backup2" "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup2\backup2"_%_isodate% /COPYALL /E /W:5 /R:5
ROBOCOPY "C:\backup3" "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup3\backup3"_%_isodate% /COPYALL /E /W:5 /R:5
ROBOCOPY "C:\backup4" "\\server\Folder1\folder2\backup4\backup4"_%_isodate% /COPYALL /E /W:5 /R:5
```

The name 'Folder' is used to indicate a regular folder, the name 'Backup' is used to indicate the backup folder.

Comment: I think the problem might be in your robocopy line. You are closing the quotes already and then append something after. So you path looks like `"\\server\Folders"_date` which you can see does not look thaaaat good ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, geisterfurz007. I will change the batch file and see if that will help.

Comment: I have tested if after the change the oldest back up will be deleted, but it doesn't work. Maybe someone has another possible sollution? The weird thing is that when I try it on my own computer and changing the date manually, it does work.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Run it from the commandline and not with double-clicking and add an `echo` in front of the lines that you think are causing the problem. With that you can check whether they are correct or not.

Comment: I going to try to find some time this week to debug the batch file

Comment: I have found some time to debug the file. It looks al OK. Maybe it has to do something with the rights the Task Scheduler is using?

Comment: I am afraid that I do not have enough knowledge about the task-scheduler rights... After debugging I assume that your batch-file is correct. So I am not able to help further, sorry.